# Is it possible to run Linux containers on Windows?

Tags: docker

Have created Linux containers using docker .
Is it possible to run Linux containers on Windows?

Comment: Yes. This is one of the purposes of Docker.

Comment: Not quite THE purpose but a very common way of running linux inside windows.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. This is possible through the power of WSL 2.

Docker Desktop, will setup WSL2 for you.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, firstly install **Docker Desktop for Windows**:

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/

and that setup **WSL 2** backend(select checkbox) via setupping:
[image]

or see more details about WSL2:
[Docker Desktop WSL2 Backend](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/#:%7E:text=Start%20Docker%20Desktop%20from%20the,will%20be%20enabled%20by%20default.)